# iframe using alternative image if orignal src unable to load content and timed out

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe tag which loads an image from a url. Is there a way such that if my url doesn't work an alternate image can be used? (server for hosting image is down, returning "url took too long to respond. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" after a few seconds).

Should work something similar to "alt" in image tag but iframe doesnt have it.

```
<iframe
        frameborder="0" style="border:0;height:410px;"
        src="myurl">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var reader = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var checkFor = "link1"; //Add the first link
    var second = "link2"; //Add the alternative

    reader.open('get', checkFor, true);
    reader.onreadystatechange = checkReadyState;

    function checkReadyState() {
        if (reader.readyState === 4) {
            if ((reader.status == 200) || (reader.status == 0)) {
            document.getElementById('site').src =  checkFor;
            }
            else {
           document.getElementById('site').src = second;
            return;
            }
        }
    }
    reader.send(null);
</script>

<iframe id="site" src=""></iframe>
```

Source: [How to Check if URL exists using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24296721/how-to-check-if-url-exists-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/808921/jake-feasel) guy

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $("iframe").not(":has([src])").each(function () {

        var ifrm = this;

        ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;

        ifrm.document.open();
        ifrm.document.write($(this).attr("alt"));
        ifrm.document.close();

        });

    });
    </script>
```

This will display the alt attribute when the src is broken.